# Parsing XML with SQL Server 2016

Tags: .net, xml, sql-server-2016

I'm trying to read only the pmc value if it is there in this structure.  I have remove node that I did not think would effect the correct answer but left the complete path

```
 <PubmedArticle>
    <MedlineCitation Status="MEDLINE" Owner="NLM">
        <PMID Version="1">29092946</PMID>        
    </MedlineCitation>
    <PubmedData>             
        <ArticleIdList>
            <ArticleId IdType="pubmed">29092946</ArticleId>
            <ArticleId IdType="pii">77/21/e79</ArticleId>
            <ArticleId IdType="doi">10.1158/0008-5472.CAN-17-0316</ArticleId>
            <ArticleId IdType="pmc">PMC5987533</ArticleId>
            <ArticleId IdType="mid">NIHMS971103</ArticleId>
        </ArticleIdList>        
    </PubmedData>
</PubmedArticle>
```

Current the code is:

```
COALESCE(nref.value('(OtherID[@Source="NLM" and text()[contains(.,"PMC")]])[1]', 'varchar(max)'), nref.value('(OtherID[@Source="NLM"][1])','varchar(max)')) PMCID,
nref.value('(Article/Journal/ISSN[@IssnType="Electronic"])[1]','varchar(15)') ISSN_Electronic,
nref.value('(Article/Journal/ISSN[@IssnType="Print"])[1]','varchar(15)') ISSN_Print
```

with the node being reference like:

```
FROM  
    [Publication.PubMed.General]  g
JOIN  
    [Publication.PubMed.AllXML] a ON a.pmid = g.pmid
CROSS APPLY  
    x.nodes('//MedlineCitation[1]') as R(nref)
WHERE 
    a.pmid = @pmid
```

I did write code to pull the pmc value a different way by

```
INSERT INTO [Publication.PubMed.ArticleIdList]  (pmid, ArticleId, IdType)
    SELECT * 
    FROM
        (SELECT DISTINCT
             pmid, nref.value('.','varchar(max)') ArticleId,
             nref.value('@IdType','varchar(max)') IdType 
         FROM
             [Publication.PubMed.AllXML]
         CROSS APPLY
             x.nodes('//PubmedData/ArticleIdList/ArticleId') as R(nref)
         WHERE 
             pmid = @pmid) t 
WHERE 
    ArticleId IS NOT NULL

DECLARE @pmc as nvarchar(25)

SET @pmc= (SELECT [ArticleId]     
           FROM [dbo].[Publication.PubMed.ArticleIdList]
           WHERE pmid = @pmid AND IdType = 'pmc')  

 UPDATE [dbo].[Publication.PubMed.General]
 SET [PMCID] = @pmc
 WHERE [PMID] =  @pmid
```

But this seems that I'm going the long way around. Thanks for any input

Comment: Please do not add an answer inline with the question - instead you should post it as an answer.

Comment: Thanks-- just did it

Comment: Thanks - and I'll delete these comments soon :)

Answer (score 0):

I think I got it-- Sometimes just writing this all out help make you think

```
 nref.value('(//PubmedData[1]/ArticleIdList/ArticleId[@IdType="pmc"])[1]','varchar(15)') PMCID
```